# Openswan and Cisco ASA

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec, openswan

i have post this same question on "Unix & Linux" but iv got no answer and will delete from there but ill try here too. I need this as soon as possible to solve it or at least to find out what is the problem. I already have configure similar scenario and works perfect, but this one i can't find way is not working as it should be. Some times i have 40% packet lost and some times i have 5% ...

I have configured IPSec tunnels with Openswan and Cisco ASA, i have established a connection and the ping was fine, but after some time there is request time out from both sites. I don't have ASA access but its default IPSec configuration,this is the openswan conf parameters.

```
#Define your IKE policy
        authby=secret
        keyingtries=0
        pfs=no
        ike=3des-sha1;modp1024
        ikelifetime="28800"

        dpddelay=0
        dpdtimeout=0
        dpdaction=clear

#Define IPSec Policy

        phase2=esp
        phase2alg=3des-sha1
        ikev2=no
        keyexchange=ike
        rekey=no
        forceencaps=no
        keylife="28800"
```

I have found this in the "/var/log/seccure" logs

```
received Delete SA(0x937bbc29) payload: deleting IPSEC State #5
received and ignored informational message
received Delete SA(0x55f62168) payload: deleting IPSEC State #8
received and ignored informational message
```

Also i like to put some more logging/debuging so i can have more info but can't find any good example or doc. on how to.

And i have the following doc. on Phase 1 and 2

```
Encryption Algorithm     3DES
Hash Algorithm           SHA1
Authentication method    Preshare
Diffie Hellman Group     Group 2
Lifetime (Key)           28800
Use NAT traversal        No
Use PFS                  No
Encapsulation            ESP
Encryption Algorithm     3DES
Hash Algorithm           SHA1
Lifetime (Key)           28800
```

Any solution or hints or some parameters that I'm missing ?

Comment: `I need this as soon as possible to solve it or at least to find out what is the problem.`  You know what works really well for that?  Hiring a consultant.  For that matter, Cisco TAC is pretty awesome.  Call them.

Comment: I'm not a Cisco consultant but im cisco certified. Yes that is the best solution, as we already have called some guys as Experts to build this tunnel and some how we can't get to work 100% or at lest 90%. So i post here if someone gave me a technical answer from experience, as this site is for.